# Spring-Integration transaction commit before rest of pipeline

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration

So, this is my current setup:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input-channel" queue-names="probni" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager"/>
<int:chain input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="inputc1">
    <int:service-activator ref="h1" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h2" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h3" method="handle" />
    <int:splitter  />
</int:chain>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputc1"/>

<int:claim-check-in input-channel="inputc1" output-channel="nullChannel" message-store="messageStore" order="1" />

<int:bridge input-channel="inputc1" output-channel="inputc2" order="2" />

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputc2" task-executor="taskExecutor" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputc2" exchange-name="exch" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" order="1" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="inputc2" output-channel="nullChannel"
                       expression="@messageStore.removeMessage(headers['id'])" order="2" />
```

and the image of this is:

[image]

What I would need is that transaction (transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager" which should be part in pink) is committed completely before any message is forwarded to int:brdige or from int:bridge (the blue arrow - so bridge is border component that should actually forward messages only if jdbc has committed).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is description why I need this kind of setup:

USE CASE: receive amqp message, process it and save to db and forward resulting amqp message down the pipeline. message should not be lost (neither arriving nor outgoing message e.g. on power loss etc.).
Multiple messages that form a sequence can arrive in multiple different processes that has same organization like below.

How I wanted to solve it:

THREAD1:

1. Receive Message from AMQP and start transaction
2. Process AMQP message in series of service-activators (possibly each activator will write to db but changes will not be saved until commit)
3. Write outgoing AMQP message to database (serialize it fully) - will not be saved until commit
4. COMMIT
5. ACK incoming message to AMQP
6. Forward outgoing message to THREAD2 in-process (not DB pointer, but real message)

THREAD2:

1. Receive message in-process from THREAD1
2. Try to send message to AMQP
3. If send successful, delete outgoing AMQP message from DB that is saved in THREAD1 step 3.

THREAD3:

1. Poll DB for messages to be sent (from THREAD1 step 3) (each 10 sec)
2. If any new message found, flag it for sending in next poll (in the meantime THREAD2 can delete this messages)
3. If on second poll (after 20sec) message is still there - means THREAD2 failed to send it, so here we spawn new thread that will do the same task as THREAD2.

**UPDATE 2**

Tried this setup, but have some problems:

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="transactionSynchronizationFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload" channel="committed-channel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input-channel" queue-names="probni" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager" advice-chain="amqpMethodInterceptor"/>
```

and:

```
@Component
public class AmqpMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private TransactionSynchronizationFactory factory;

    public AmqpMethodInterceptor(TransactionSynchronizationFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {


        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
            TransactionSynchronization synchronization = factory.create("123");
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(synchronization);
        }

        Object result = invocation.proceed();

        return result;
    }
}
```

after-commit is called, but the message is null at this point in time, so seems like I have nothing to forward to committed-channel. Any idea how to do this part?

Comment: What is the purpose of this solution, BTW? Why the regular way as "everything in the `transaction-manager`" thread doesn't work for you? If TX fails, the message isn't acked on the RabbitMQ Broker.

Comment: Well, in this case how you explained, there is possibilty that transaction fails after send() method. That means that jdbc rolled back but amqp outbound adapter already sent the message (in other thread in this case) - situation that should not happen.

Comment: Also i need to ACK message before sending it here, and transaction will ack it only afterwards (if in same thread).

Comment: You don't need JDBC in that case and you don't need that `publish-subscribe-channel` with an `executor`. Just because there won't be any `claim-check` to worry about. You receive message from the RabbitMQ perform some logic (not `claim-check` ) and send result to the other AMQP exchange. Everything in the same TX started in the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: Why? What is the point to ack it before sending somewhere? How about if send fails? Having your explanation it looks like inconsistency. The message is acked but its subsequent process is failed.

Comment: Yes. That is why I have it saved to db. I have also additional db poller with check-out. It will check for messages in db each 10 sec. On first check it will buffer the message. If the same mesage is there after second check (20 sec. Passed), i will take it from db and send to ampq + remove from store.

Comment: Why? What is the requirements? Looks like you have introduced that `claim-check` for nothing, when the same RabbitMQ Broker can be used as a message persistence storage. And you try to overcome TX boundaries with that `executor`. That's why you have all that mess. Just drop `claim-check` and perform all your logic in the same thread! I don't see reason in that extra `executor`.

Comment: I suppose i can loose the message beeing propagated? I jdbc commit suceeds, and amqp forward fails + amqp ack fails, message will be redelivered here, but since I already processed here, I will just discard it. This way the amqp foward is lost.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need JDBC commit there if you drop `claim-check` in your logic.

Comment: OTOH there is `QueueChannel` with the same JDBC `MessageStore`. And message will be available there for downstream polling only if TX is committed and message is acked on the Broker.

Comment: I'm so nasty because your use-case doesn't look like an appropriate for the Claim-Check pattern...

Comment: Well i dont need really claim-check, i just need to persist message to database and delete it after sending (either inmediatelly or if something fails after 20 sec)

Comment: It is really deleted from the persistent `QueueChannel` on poller's TX commit. The send part should be included to this TX. IF TX fail, the message remain is DB and is available for the next polling task. The ` 20 sec` looks like `Time-To-Live` for messages, which you can achieve manually via `JdbcMessageStore.registerMessageGroupExpiryCallback(MessageGroupCallback)` iteration.

Comment: Yes, but in case of queue, i have to use poller. This way i just wanted to forward msg immediatelly (and not from database). Database should be read by this other poller only if message is not forwarded (e.g. failed) by first thread (if fw, it will also be deleted from db).

Comment: OK. So, forward it as is and send to the DB (`QueueChannel`), only in case of error. The `Executor` in the channel is wrapped with the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`, where you can move the `failedMessage` to the persistent `QueueChannel`.

Comment: Is this pos:forward to jdbc backed queue and directly to amqp. If amqp sent, i del from q (and db). If msg in queue 20sec. Send from queue to amqp and dlt

Comment: Is adding to db backed queue done in same transaction as amqp:inbound and before ACK?

Comment: Yes, in the same TX. Commit to DB and ACK on Broker is done in the end of TX.

Comment: Queue is a bit problematic here, since I need at first queue poll not to consume messages but just flag them as ready to send in next run. In the mean time other thread should be able to remove msgs from queue (without any order). So I would need some sort of database backed set with transactional check-and-set option. I dont think queue supports this? I can post better description what I actually need if I was too confusing.

Comment: Yes, please, provide the business requirements for your task. Then we may come up with some solution for you. Any way that claim-check jumping doesn't look promising here.

Comment: That's still not business requirements, but your vision how to fix. OK. Let it be. There is no any out-of-the-box components to help you. Especially something like "flag it for sending in next poll". So, you have to implement all the custom logic yourself and take into account that my answer about `TransactionSynchronization`. I think you even can use `JdbcMessageStore` manually for this task. But that is different story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible only with the `TransactionSynchronization`.

The bridge is really the "border" of the TX, but commit here happens really after the `send()` method. Just because your next channel is with an `executor`, so, the current transactional thread has nothing to do more and performs commit only after send, not before.

For your goal you should implement `MethodInterceptor` advice to inject into `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` via `advice-chain`. And try to utilize logic of the `DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory` with the `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor`, where you will be able to send message to the `afterCommitChannel`.

Your code in the `Advice` should use this template:

```
if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
                TransactionSynchronization synchronization = this.transactionSynchronizationFactory.create(key);
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(synchronization);
}
```

where `key` can be any unique object to distinguish resource synced with the TX.

**UPDATE**

> but the message is null at this point in time, so seems like I have nothing to forward to committed-channel.

That's true because you use `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` with unusual manner.

Well, let's try to trick it anyway, because for me you go right way.

The `factory.create("123");` does this:

```
    DefaultTransactionalResourceSynchronization synchronization = new DefaultTransactionalResourceSynchronization(key);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(key, synchronization.getResourceHolder());
    return synchronization;
```

The main point there is `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource()`. My idea here somewhere downstream, before the end of TX, do this:

```
IntegrationResourceHolder holder =
                    (IntegrationResourceHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource("123");
holder.setMessage(message);
```

I think that even can be possible with this:

```
 <int:outbound-channel-adapter 
        expression="T(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager).getResource('123').setMessage(#root)"/>
```

as the last endpoint before exiting from the TX.

Comment: Can you please check UPDATE 2, since I have some problems with implementing this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I have a problem with getResource('123') since it founds this method on class and not on TransactionSynchronizationManager. Class has getResource with String type and TransactionSynchronizationManager has getResource with Object, so somehow I have to tell spring that it should use one with Object argument.

Comment: Try this instead: `T(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager).resourceMap[123].setMessage(#root)`

Comment: Still error: EL1011E:(pos 94): Method call: Attempted to call method setMessage(org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage) on null context object

Comment: But this one works: T(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchro‌​nizationManager).res‌​ourceMap['123'].setMes‌​sage(#root); thanks.

Comment: Great! Accept the answer, please, and let's go to other tasks!

Comment: I suppose that ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor does not support sync of List of message objects (can see that holder has only one), since I have a list of messages that are all committed at once?

Comment: Seems like I had to re-implement IntegrationResourceHolder as IntegrationResourcesHolder (and a lot of other classes) in order to support List<Message<?>>. Anyway it is doable. Should I commit to the git of integration project?

Comment: Several messages at once? This is a new income and fully different story. Although you can use aggregator to keep messages in the store and release a list of them

Comment: I modified the IntegrationResourcesHolder  and commited merge request on the project on github. It seems like it is working OK for me if I let multiple messages to be stored in same holder. I suppose that aggreagator would also be the option, but then I need to introduce splitter again in another thread...